# How to use tools like gitg and gitk in windows with wsl ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5, wsl-2, gitk, gitg

How to use tools like gitg and gitk in windows with wsl ubuntu 22.04 ?
I have windows 11 and installed wsl on in have ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it,
Now How to use the tools like gitg na gitk on it like we do in ubuntu 22.04.

Its gives Error on console:

```
vidur@DESKTOP-R3GUP0B:~/rails_app/abcdocsbackend$ gitg
Failed to parse options: Cannot open display:
```

Comment: WSL do not support the tools like gitk and gitg. Need to use source tree for bitbucket.